# Spring DATA JPA with Hibernate as JPA provider

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Using Spring boot application with spring data jpa with hibernate as jpa provider.

Created one default method in one interface which is extending JpaRepository.

Please check the code.

```
public interface UserDao extends JpaRepository<User, UUID> {

default void softDelete(UUID id) {
    User existingUser = findOne(id);

    if (existingUser != null)
        existingUser.setActive(false);

    throw new EntityNotFoundException();
    }
}
```

Now when I am calling this **softDelete()** from the service layer, it does not return existing user. It is returning as NULL.

This is the log stack trace.

```
    2017-08-27 13:25:01 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaObjectRetrievalFailureException: nested exception is javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException] with root cause
javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: null
    at org.rout.projmgmt.dao.UserDao.softDelete(UserDao.java:31)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle.invokeWithArguments(MethodHandle.java:627)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:62)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy107.softDelete(Unknown Source)
    at org.rout.projmgmt.service.user.UserServiceImpl.delete(UserServiceImpl.java:53)
    at org.rout.projmgmt.controller.UserController.delete(UserController.java:53)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doDelete(FrameworkServlet.java:894)
```

Any idea what I am missing ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple of things:

1. You would always get an `EntityNotFoundException` exception irrespective of whether you get the record or not because i am assuming you want to send that exception when you dont find any record.
2. You may want to return back the user too, but your return type is void. I would modify the return type to be User instead as below:

   ```
   default User softDelete(UUID id) {
       User existingUser = findOne(id);
       if (existingUser != null) {
           existingUser.setActive(false);
       } else {
           throw new EntityNotFoundException();
       }
       return existingUser;//you may want to save this user again with isActive flag now false
   }
   ```

Comment: OMG. I just forgot my java basics. I am so sorry for even posting this question. But thanks a lot everybody. It was just so stupid. :(

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer provided by SMA also couple of things.

1. I do not recall right now but AFAIR it is advised to also name custom classes extending **Spring Data Repository** as **Repository** and not **Dao**.
2. Are You sure that You are having this user in a DB? How do you initialize the database - Flyway? Spring Boot automatic ***schema.sql*** and ***data.sql*** files?
3. With the code You've provided exception will be thrown even if the entity is in the DB.

Answer (score 0):

SMA got your question spot on! I just have to add that you should try using the JpaRepository without putting any logic inside, just use it for CRUD operations and do the logic in your service layer. Like so:

```
public interface UserDao extends JpaRepository<User, UUID> {

@Modifying
@Query("update User u set u.active = false where u.id = :id")
default User softDelete(@Param("id) UUID id) throws EntityNotFoundException;
}
```

and then you can do the error handling in your service.
The [reference docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.modifying-queries) are showing some great examples for writing custom queries to better match your needs